# How to calculate the flow rate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, flow, bernoulli-equation

Given a tank with a certain height of water above the discharge pipe of know length, open to the atmosphere at the other end. I know the flow rate can be calculated if the pipe was horizontal by using Poiseuille's equation (No entry losses, no turbine or pump work, pipe cross-section is constant) by considering the pressure loss to be equal to the difference between the hydrostatic pressure at the inlet of the pipe and the atmospheric pressure.

If the pipe was not horizontal.. ie the pipe outlet is at a certain distance below the inlet to the pipe, by knowing the length of the pipe and not considering any pipe bend losses can we calculate the flow rate?....I considered using Bernoulli's equation by considering the pressure drop to be equal to the difference between the hydrostatic pressure at the inlet of the pipe and the atmospheric pressure and as the height difference between the inlet and outlet is know. I couldn't figure out how to calculate the pressure loss term in the equation. Is this data sufficient to calculate the flow rate...if not what other data would be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I considered using Bernoulli's equation by considering the pressure
>   drop to be equal to the difference between the hydrostatic pressure at
>   the inlet of the pipe and the atmospheric pressure and as the height
>   difference between the inlet and outlet is known.

Assuming an open vessel and the outlet to atmospheric pressure also:

[image: Vessel]

Then the total pressure available to overcome pipe pressure losses is:

$$\Delta P=\rho g h$$

(with $\rho$ the density of the fluid)

As regards the pressure loss in the pipe, assume no losses in the bends (if any) and **assume laminar flow**, so you can use the [Hagen Poiseulle equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation):

$$\Delta P=\frac{8\mu Q}{\pi R^4}L$$

Then calculate the flow rate. Check the [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) $Re$ to see if flow is indeed laminar.

Should flow prove not to be laminar ($Re>2600$), you will need the [Darcy Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation) for **turbulent flow** to calculate the pressure loss in the pipe:

$$\Delta P=f_D\frac{8Q^2}{\pi^2 g D^5}L$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Hagen Poiseulle equation would give the irreversible pressure loss in the pipe. Pressure drop in the pipe would include reversible and irreversible loss. Given a horizontal pipe pressure drop (ΔP=ρgh) would be equal to pressure loss. But i am not talking about a horizontal pipe here.  [Continued]

Comment: ....  P1/ρg +(V1)^2/2g+z1=P2/ρg+(V2)^2/2g+z2+hloss    .... is the equation I think, where ΔP=ρgh=P1-P2 is the pressure drop. How to calculate  hloss which is the irreversible pressure loss?

Comment: ALL pressure loss in the pipe is **irreversible**, because it is due to friction and thus not conserved.

Comment: The calculation I gave you is standard textbook, for horizontal or vertical (and in between) pipes. It's approximate because it doesn't take into account losses in the vessel (small), inlet of pipe, bends etc.

Comment: ...Not all pressure losses are irreversible. Consider the pipe going up and down....as the pipe goes up the pressure reduces due to gravitational effects...and as the pipe goes down that pressure is recovered.

Comment: Those are not losses: they are variations in the hydrostatic pressure due to height variations, already accounted for by Bernoulli. They are not due to friction. Bernoulli clearly shows only the OVERALL height difference is needed. It is easy to understand, IMO.

Comment: Yup, that's why I mentioned them(Pressure variation due to height or due to converging section)  as pressure drop. Only the pressure drop due to viscous effect as pressure loss.

Comment: In my opinion HP equation can be used only for horizontal pipes.

Comment: That is COMPLETELY wrong. Look at any text relevant on the subject. Precisely because it only takes into account the friction losses can it be used for any type of pipe, assuming constant $R$, of course. For bent ones too, because the pressure loss in bends, valves etc is accounted for separately, usually based on measurement. This is not a matter of 'opinion'.

Comment: Found this useful but still figuring it out. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270882/friction-loss-in-a-vertical-pipe-flow Maybe you are right and my understanding wrong. Still studying.

Comment: The link confirms what I said. For non-horizontal pipes, the *height* of the pipe needs to be taken into account, in the overall available pressure, as I did in my answer. I could have written $P=\rho g(h_{tank}+h_{pipe})$ but that would not have changed things one iota. HG is about friction losses: ask yourself if friction losses depend on direction  of flow? They do NOT, of course. Viscous friction is viscous friction, no matter the orientation of the flow.

Comment: Exactly! frictional losses do not depend on the direction of the flow, and the and the changes due to gravitational potential is taken care by considering overall height. Thank you. I got it. The confusion was due to many fluid dynamics books not giving the derivation of the HP equation  a stating it's for horizontal pipes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem solved by following method not sure if its right:
Suppose a tank with cross section are of A
And the outlet area is a
Flow rate of pipe is I
So after t seconds I.t volume of water comes out and the water is coming from top of tank 
So there is almost I.t/A height decreased so its energy is of this voulme comes from top of tank to inlet:
U = K => g h = v v /2
V = sqrt(2 g h)
V a t = volume of water out = I.t
I = sqrt(2 g h) * a
This assumes the tank has opening on the top

Comment: This is a haphazard way to answer. Difficult to understand. I think this will be proper because u have equated the water lever decrease in tank 'h' to kinetic energy increase ....so by this as water level goes on decreasing kinetic energy should go on increasing ..which would mean velocity and flow rate should go on increasing in a pipe of constant cross-section area which is wrong.

Comment: h is distance from surface of  water  to oulet

Comment: Ok...If h is the height of water from the outlet then according to g h = v v /2 potential head is fully converted to the dynamic head which > But I am looking for an answer when there are losses in the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You are really asking how you calculate the term $h_{loss}$ in applying the Bernoulli equation to a non-horizontal pipe.  The equations given in @Gert's response are the correct ones to use if you simply replace the $\Delta P$'s on the left hand sides of his equations by $\rho gh_{loss}$ and regard L as the length of pipe.  This will give you the correct result for $\rho gh_{loss}$ both for horizontal and vertical pipes.